# Iot Core API /api/wifi/network - Bug?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

The [Device Portal Core API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-api-core) contains a Post method for connecting/disconnecting Wifi. [This project](https://github.com/FalafelSoftwareInc/WindowIoTCoreWifiInitTest) by Falafel is a demonstration of that.
All other methods in that project work fine but when trying to connect, the response returned is StatusCode 500 **"Internal server error"**. I'm running Windows Iot Core v.10.0.16299.309 on a Raspberry Pi3.

The portals authentication is built and passed in the request and the wifi Key is encoded in base 64. The request uri will look something like the following.
http://192.168.137.1:8080/api/wifi/network?interface=1A6E4125-B554-40CB-916E-EE55CEBAD6C8&op=connect&ssid=MyWifiSSID&key=42dhi2nuk%182v&createprofile=yes

Does anyone see something wrong with this approach or can the error be duplicated? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need **encode WiFi SSID** to base64 format. In C# you can do it like this:

```
        byte[] stringToBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(wifiSsid);
        string encodedValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(stringToBytes);
```

For your referenced [project](https://github.com/FalafelSoftwareInc/WindowIoTCoreWifiInitTest), you need use `EncodeTo64(this.SelectedWifi.SSID)` instead of `this.SelectedWifi.SSID` in the Post method for connecting Wifi like this:

```
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("http://[IP ADDRESS]:8080/api/wifi/network?interface={1}&ssid={2}&op=connect&createprofile=yes&key={3}", this.DeviceName, this.InterfaceGUID, EncodeTo64(this.SelectedWifi.SSID), EncodeTo64(this.WifiKey)), null))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks again for your help.